# PHP Array Logic - Timeslots with Appointment Duration

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of time slots in 15 minutes intervals (Hours:Minutes e.g. 11:00, 11.15).

```
Array
(
[0] => 11:00
[1] => 11:15
[2] => 11:30
[3] => 11:45
[4] => 13:00
[5] => 13:15
)
```

There above array would therefore indicate that between 11:00 and 12:00 is free.

I then have an appointment duration in minutes e.g. 60 minutes or 90 minutes.

I need to use some logic to work our whether the time slots are available based on the appointment duration. So if the appointment duration was 30 minutes I would expect the final array to be this:

```
Array
(
[0] => 11:00
[1] => 11:15
[2] => 11:30
[3] => 13:00
)
```

11:45 and 13:15 are not included because 11:45 to 12:00 and 13:15 to 13:30 are only 15 minutes and therefore would not fit.

If the appointment duration was 60 minutes I would expect the array to be

```
Array
(
[0] => 11:00
)
```

Appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing any code yet?

Comment: Your question almost makes sense you only missing the logic!

Comment: I can't get my head round how to do it! My thinking is to loop round each of the time slots then see how many slots are required for the appointment e.g. 30 mins = 2. The issue I cant work out is how to deal with ensuring they are 4 consecutive slots as if I choose 11:45 then technically there are 2 slots after but one is 11:45 - 12:00 the other is 13:00 - 13:15 which is obviously not good. The appointment duration may also not be divisible by 15 as it could be 80 mins etc.

Comment: yes, you would need to loop through each time slot, and check if there enough consecutive slots. To deal with non-15 min increaments use [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) to round up to the next whole number when dividing your time by 15

Comment: I have provided my code, please advise if you would of done it a better way :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am feeling a little generous, and needed the brain exercise, so here is a possible example.

(1) you need to determine how many extra/continuous slots that would be needed. As your slots are 15 min increments, you will need to divide your appointment needed by 15. If you allow non-15 min incremented appointments, you will need to use [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) to round up to a whole number.

```
$blocks_needed = ceil($appointment_length/15);
```

You would subtract `1`, if you just want the additional block amount

```
$additional_blocks_needed = ceil($appointment_length/15)-1;
```

(2) you need to loop through your slots array, and check if there is `$blocks_needed` continuous slots. Or simply, you can check if there is an array value at `$additional_blocks_needed` position from the current time slot AND that it is `$appointment_length` minutes from the current time slot

I did it as a function so that it is repeatable

```
function get_available_times($slots_array,$appointment_length){

    // get 0-based additional blocks needed    
    $additional_blocks_needed = (ceil($appointment_length/15))-1;

    // set an empty array    
    $available = array();

    // loop through each $slot_array value    
    foreach($slots_array as $key=>$block){

        // start with available as false
        $slot_available = false;

        // check if (1) there is a value at the `$key+($additional_blocks_needed)` slot
        // AND
        // check it the time from the last slot and the current slot is correct
        if( isset($slots_array[$key+($additional_blocks_needed)]) && 
        (strtotime($slots_array[$key+($additional_blocks_needed)])-strtotime($slots_array[$key]) == 900*($additional_blocks_needed)) )
        {
            // if both conditions are met, change to true
            $slot_available=true;
        }
        // if true, then add to the available array
        if($slot_available)
        {
            $available[]=$slots_array[$key];
        }
    }
    // return the array of available slots
    return $available;
}
```

You can test the function with -

```
// your array of slots
$slots = array('11:00','11:15','11:30','11:45','13:00','13:15','13:30');

// loop through 10 min increments to see if there are available time slots   
for($appointment=10;$appointment<=90;$appointment+=5){
    $check = get_available_times($slots,$appointment);
    echo "<pre>{$appointment}: ".print_r($check,1)."</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I have done it, appreciate any advice on improving the code.

```
$slotsNeeded = ceil($durationMinutes/15);

if($slotsNeeded <= count($workingSlotsReal)){
foreach($workingSlotsReal as $key => $value){

    $notEnough = 0;

    for($i = $key; $i < $key+$slotsNeeded; $i++){

        if(!array_key_exists($i,$workingSlotsReal)){
            $notEnough++;
        }

    }

    if($notEnough > 0){
        unset($workingSlotsReal[$key]);
    }

}
} else {
unset($workingSlotsReal);
}
```

Comment: if this is your solution, then it is okay to post as an answer. If you want advice on improving the code, you should edit your question, not post as an answer.